# Spring data specification - dynamic condition

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I'm using below code to filter and extract the data for the entity

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification;

List<ServerAttributes> serverAttributesList = serverAttributesRepository
        .findAll(Specification.where(spec1).and(spec2).and(spec3));
```

but now i have variable number of specification , how can i add the specification in the where clause at runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
Specification spec = Specification.where(null);
if ({condition}) {
  spec = spec.and(spec1);
}
List<SomeEntity> list = repo.findAll(spec);
```